# How can I override property setting for a dict-like object?

Tags: python

I'm writing a C binding, and the C structure that I'm wrapping has some string-indexed property values.

I'd like to expose these as a dict in python.

So far, I've got a function `get_properties`, which returns all the object's properties as a single dict.  I wrapped this using the `property` function in the class definition, so that I can access it as a class attribute:

(in class definition)

```
class MyClass:
    def get_properties(self):
        ...
    properties = property(get_properties)
```

(example)

```
>>> print myobj.properties
{'test': 5, 'test2': 'string'}
```

Now, I'd like to handle setting them in a dict-like way.  I have a wrapper function for the C function called `set_property`, which takes a string key and a value of several types.

I tried using `set_properties` from my class `property`:

```
class MyClass:
    def get_properties(self):
        ...
    def set_property(self, key, value):
        ...
    def set_properties(self, props):
        [self.set_property(k, props[k]) for k in props]
    properties = property(get_properties, set_properties)
```

This works like this following:

```
>>> myobj.properties = {"test3": 6}
>>> print myobj.properties
{'test': 5, 'test2': 'string', 'test3': 6}
```

However, as you can see it's not entirely the expected behaviour.  What I'd prefer is something like:

```
>>> myobj.properties['test3'] = 6
```

I tried adding a definition for `__setitem__` to `properties`:

```
class MyClass:
    ...
    properties = property(get_properties)
    properties.__setitem__ = set_property
```

But this got me,

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__setitem__'
```

I tried to make property a dict and simply override `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` but it wouldn't have it.

Any idea what the correct way to do this is?  Can I make a class `property` behave like a dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, Mike's answer gave me the idea to solve this by returning from the property's getter with an extended dict class, in which I override `__setitem__` based on the context:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def get_properties():
        ... (call C function and convert to dict)
    def set_property():
        ... (call C function)
    def propgetter(self):
        context = self
        props = self.get_properties()
        class propsetter(dict):
            __getitem__ = props.__getitem__
            def __setitem__(self, key, value):
                props[key] = value
                context.set_property(key, value)
        return propsetter(self.get_properties())
    properties = property(propgetter)
```

Seems to work as I want.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've defined your property it is read only.  However, the property decorator actually optionally takes set and get functions:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {"hello":None}
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.d,)
    def get(self):
        return self.d
    def set(self, value):
        self.d = value
    x = property(get, set)
```

By defining a setter for your internal dictionary you can now set keys on it:

```
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.x
{'hello': None}
>>> c.x["hello"] = "world"
>>> c.x
{'hello': 'world'}
>>> c.x = {"key":"value"}
>>> c.x
{'key': 'value'}
```

Also, if you're using a more recent version of Python (2.6+) you could write this a nicer way with decorators like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {"hello":None}
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.d,)
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.d
    @x.setter
    def set(self, value):
        self.d = value
```

Comment: I'm afraid in your example, the setter is never called.  You're using the underlying dict representation through the getter.  I'm trying to _intercept_ the dict-like `__setitem__` call and replace it with my C library's representation.

Comment: In your question you said: "However, as you can see it's not entirely the expected behaviour. What I'd prefer is something like:

>>> myobj.properties['test3'] = 6".  By adding a setter that example works was my only point.  Anyway, so you're really looking for how to subclass dict in the C Python API or how to implement the dict interface for a builtin type?  How are you currently wrapping your C data structure and making it available to Python?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  But I want myobj.properties['test3'] to call _my_ version of `__setitem__`, which is not what your example does.